# How to sum up multiple time records on a given date in database. Error:Subquery returned more than 1 value

Tags: c#, sql-server, date, time

I have a stop watch and a database. I want to be able to report how much time in the whole database was recorded `in total on a given date`.

The x date is given by a datetimepicker.

When I click relative button in my C# program in order to sum up the time with my "SumOnDateReport" stored procedure, I get this error:

> Additional information: Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

How I managed to do it:

- record the time with stopwatch
- save the label.text into the database
- substring(devide) the text in 3 sections(hh:mm:ss)
- convert them to integer
- convert them to seconds (eg. hh*3600/ mm*60)
- add them together
- divide them by 60 to report them as minutes

your needed information:

My table(with pre-entered data):

```
id  TimeSpanColumn TimeStampColumn TimeStringColumn TotalSecColumn
------------------------------------------------------------------
1   23:12:50    2011/07/12 12:00:00     NULL           NULL
2   2:07:24     2012/03/09 12:00:00     NULL           NULL
3   54:17:52    2013/03/09 12:00:00     NULL           NULL
```

My addtime C# code (via stored procedure):

```
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.Today;
timer1.Stop();

sqlcon.Open();

SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand("AddTime", sqlcon);
sqlcmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@QTimeSpan", label1.Text + ":" + label3.Text + ":" + label5.Text);
sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@QTimeStamp", dateTime);
sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@QTimeString", label1.Text + label3.Text + label5.Text);

sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();  

SqlDataAdapter sqlda = new SqlDataAdapter("GetSavedInfo", sqlcon);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
sqlda.Fill(dt);

dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;   

sqlcon.Close();
```

My addTime stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE AddTime
     @QTimeSpan NVARCHAR(50),
     @QTimeStamp DATETIME,
     @QTimeString NVARCHAR(50)
AS   
     INSERT INTO InfoTable (TimeSpanColumn, TimeStampColumn, TimeStringColumn) 
     VALUES (@QTimeSpan, @QTimeStamp, @QTimeString)

     RETURN
```

My report on a date C# code:

```
 SqlDataAdapter sqlda = new SqlDataAdapter("SumOnDateReport", sqlcon);
 sqlda.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

 sqlda.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@QueryDate", dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"));

 DataTable dt = new DataTable();
 sqlda.Fill(dt);

 dataGridView2.DataSource = dt;
```

My SumOnDateReport stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SumOnDateReport
    @QueryDate DATETIME
AS
    DECLARE @total_sec INT
    DECLARE @HourTime INT
    DECLARE @MinTime INT
    DECLARE @SecTime INT

    SET @HourTime = (SELECT CONVERT(INT, SUBSTRING(TimeStringColumn, 1, 2)) 
                     FROM InfoTable 
                     WHERE TimeStampColumn = @QueryDate)
    SET @MinTime = (SELECT CONVERT(INT, SUBSTRING(TimeStringColumn, 3, 2)) 
                    FROM InfoTable 
                    WHERE TimeStampColumn = @QueryDate)
    SET @SecTime = (SELECT CONVERT(INT, SUBSTRING(TimeStringColumn, 5, 2)) 
                    FROM InfoTable 
                    WHERE TimeStampColumn = @QueryDate)
    SET @total_sec = @HourTime * 3600 + @MinTime * 60 + @SecTime

    INSERT INTO InfoTable(TotalSecColumn) 
    VALUES (@total_sec)

    SELECT TotalSecColumn 
    FROM InfoTable
    WHERE TimeStampColumn = @QueryDate
```

Comment: Use `select` to assign to a variable instead of `set` if your query returns more than 1 record. If the variable is not a table, the last value from the query will be assigned to the variable. This is what the error is about because you are using `=` but the subquery returns more than a single value. See [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/select-local-variable-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) for more.

Comment: Unrelated tips: SqlConnection SqlCommand and SqlDataAdapter are all IDisposable so each should be in a `using` block. Once you've done that, you don't need to Close the connection because it will be closed by the implicit Dispose as it exits the block. You may also want to read [can we stop using AddWithValue](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/).

Comment: @CodingYoshi would you please tell me how can I do the process part(the set part). I used set cause I tought if I use select it would be selected and shown in the database...

Comment: There are examples in the link which is in my comment. Please tell me in plain English what do you want to do in `SumOnDateReport`.

Comment: Okay thank you. Do you see the bullet points in my question? I have to do those operations in my project to be able to sum up times. do you see the only answer in this page? he is right, I have more than one record in my `InfoTable` with the same value in `TimeStampColumn` matching my value for `@QueryDate`. **BUT** if we have two or three `TimeStamp` in the data base that are the same, it means they are equal. so the computer should go over and process the information corresponding to those TimeStamps(In my case sum the Time`Span` column up)... why couldnt it figure it out? @CodingYoshi

Comment: Why would the computer figure it out? As a programmer, you need to figure it out and tell the computer what to do. Anyhow, does the answer below solve your problem?

Comment: No It doesnt. because it only says the computer cant understand if _you have more than one record in InfoTable with the same value in Time**stamp** Column matching your value for @querydate._ It doesnt tell me how am I able to `add` the values of time **Span** column together when _I have more than one record in my table with the same value in TimeStamp Column matching my value for @querydate._

Comment: sorry I forgot to mention you in the above comment. I answerd your question. @CodingYoshi . thank you for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will get this error if you have more than one record in `InfoTable` with the same value in `TimeStampColumn` matching your value for `@QueryDate`.  You will need to change those subqueries to ensure they return a single record.  In this case I think you want to `SUM` those values.

```
set @HourTime = (select SUM(CONVERT(int,substring(TimeStringColumn,1,2))) 
from InfoTable WHERE TimeStampColumn=@QueryDate)
set @MinTime =  (select SUM(CONVERT(int,substring(TimeStringColumn,3,2)))
from InfoTable WHERE TimeStampColumn=@QueryDate)
set @SecTime =  (select SUM(CONVERT(int,substring(TimeStringColumn,5,2)))
from InfoTable WHERE TimeStampColumn=@QueryDate)
```